# how to export html form with canvas to pdf

Tags: html, forms, pdf, apk, offline

I am trying to export an html page that contains html form and canvas to a pdf file (after onclick event (button)). I already been aware of wkhtmltopdf and PhantomJS but I think that it cannot be implemented as it should. 
(the main problem is that I want to export the output offline, by covnerting the web app to android apk  using the http://www.appsgeyser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To get your requirement, I hope you require to take pdf of web page.

if my understanding is correct, Please refer below link

http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx

also see the existing post ITextSharp HTML to PDF?

Follow the Link of Zend_Pdf : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html

You can also try jspdf : http://jspdf.com/

Or try to use javascript